# Insert an UItableView in UITableViewCell causes lag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to use a `UITableView` to display news,and inserting another tablview in the news cell to display the comment,but I got some issue,I make the cell to be the child table's datasource,and return the height like below

```
-(void)setReplayArray:(NSArray *)replayArray
{
    _replayArray = replayArray;
    [_replyTableView reloadData];
    CGFloat h = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < _replayArray.count; i++)
    {
        h = h+ [self tableView:_replyTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    _replyTableViewHeight.constant = (_replayArray&&_replayArray.count>0)?h+10:h;
}
```

and set like this in father's datasource

```
        newCell.replayArray = comment.replyArray;
```

but it causes lag when I scroll the tableview,what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Inserting a tableview inside a cell it's a very bad idea. Use labels or textviews inside the cell and expand it if need more space

Comment: i'll try another way,thanks